# should I create a million queues (Python)

Tags: python, queue

As a hobby I like creating market tools for day traders. I'm running into an issue.

I have a list of Stocks
`AAPL,M,AA.....`

Every 15 minutes I loop through and check for a condition we'll call `c`
`if c==True` I want to store this so I can check another condition against it next time I loop.

For example, using the list above lets say `AA` meets the condition `c` and I place `AA` in a queue along with other data so i can check in next loop .
Example: `(AA,price,date)` . 
On the next loop I'll need to pull out the ticker to see if it matches the index I'm currently processing.

sudo here

`checkQueue = queue.Queue()`

`for ticker in list:
     if c():
       checkQueue.put(ticker)`

During the next loop I start with `AAPL`. This means I need to pop from the queue to see if the ticker matches. I understand that I can do something like the following
`if ticker !=checkQueue.get()
  checkQueue.put(ticker)`

Though doing the above means that I will be getting and putting 2 times before it reaches `AA`. If i have 10000 stocks that could potentially be 9999 get/puts.

Is there a way for me to ONLY interact with a queue who matches the ticker? Should I make 10000 queues and only put something in the tickers queue who i'm currently processing? Seems a little silly and figure there is a better way.

Comment: At this scale, "don't queue it, just do it".

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need a solution with set(). the first for-loop to iterate only the stock recorded previously.

```
stocks = [AAPL, M, AA...]
check_later_set = set()
def run_every_15min(stocks):
    for stock in check_later_set:
        if not c(stock):
            check_later_set.remove(stock)

    for stock in stocks:
        if c(stock):
            check_later_set.add(stock)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Just realized this would not work for my case. Probably should have added additional information. Editing my post....